# Как определить xpath путь для элемента таблицы

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте! Начинаю изучать Selenium webdriver и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Как я могу определить xpath путь элемента из таблички? Пробовал запускать просмотр исходного кода страницы в chrome, после - выделял элемент и выбирал получить xpath
При этом Selenium webdriver ругается на то, что он не может найти этот элемент.
Пытаюсь сделать с этой табличкой:
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDriver не может найти элемент, т.к. элемент который вы ищите находится во iframe...

Неудачный вы взяли пример для обучения)

Можете конечно попробовать переключить WebDriver на нужный вам фрейм и после уже искать элемент

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2); // или 1 - не помню с какой цифры начинают они нумероваться
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
```